# Is it possible to write a parental control app for iOS?

Tags: ios, parental-control, feasibility

Is it possible to have parental control in iOS? Like the admin can decide which app user can access, restrict internet access , contacts, photos etc for particular user?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

<strike>This is not possible for a third-party app and a non-jailbroken device. Did you look at Settings → General → Restrictions? It’s not exactly what you’re after, but it’s a good start.</strike>

Actually, this *is* possible, using the [Device Enrollment Program](http://images.apple.com/education/docs/DEP_Guide.pdf). ([This YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iYOWGKZjues) found by Kudi shows the device enrollment profile installation procedure.) The DEP is mostly meant for large companies managing their company devices, but apparently it can also be used for other features. It would be interesting to hear the details from somebody who has jumped through the hoops, I have no experience with DEP myself.

Comment: Hi i just found one app. If you say this is not possible without jailbreak. Then how they are able to do that.

App name is OurPact

Comment: The app is so secure it’s not even available for download in my country, so I have no idea how it works.

Comment: Here is the youtube video link :- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iYOWGKZjues

This is how it works.

Comment: You’re right! So it is possible. AFAIK this is the Device Enrollment Program in action, see my updated answer.

Comment: It is actually MDM that enforces the policies. DEP automates the MDM enrolment process and ensures that MDM restrictions cannot be removed even by erasing the device

Comment: @Awesome.Apple did you find any complete tutorial for MDM? because no one gives complete knowledge.

Comment: Link is broken.

Answer (score 0):

For restrict internet access, it can be achieved with new introduced [NetworkExtension API of iOS 9](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2015/?id=717).