# iOS remote control app development

Tags: android, ios, mobile-devices

I have to create iOS/Android application to control child device from parent device. 
For iOS i found that i have to use MDM server with Apple Device Enrollment Program (DEP) and install a profile on the child device. As DEP is not available in my country, is it possible to create MDM server myself and is there anything special about it?
I suppose, that the controlling application on the parent device has to send changes to the MDM server, which then sends them to the child's device. Is that correct?
Is it possible to control iOS device from Android device and vise versa?

I read all the posts related to this topic but there is no detailed answer:
[How to do Parent Control App in iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36475366/how-to-do-parent-control-app-in-ios)
[Ourpact Parenting Control IOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32224347/ourpact-parenting-control-ios)
[Is it possible to write a parental control app for iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32220377/is-it-possible-to-write-a-parental-control-app-for-ios)