# to block the particular website from another phone in react native

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, react-native, npm

Hello i'm working on a security app. in which parent want to block a particular websites from child phone. like:
type of content. 
-Abortion 
-Adult 
-Drugs
-Mature
-Nudity
-Pornography
-Weapons  etc.
i want that parent will be able to block these website from their phone. i have two modules of the app parent and child app . in which parent can access their child phone. and able to block the websites.

I get the idea about blocking a particular website but i'm not sure to block that from another phone like through parent phone.

Any help will be appreciated.
for screen time.
main goal is blocking the content and filter the content

Comment: you should ask this one  on ask different.

Comment: @AbuUlHassan sorry i didn't get you.

Comment: ask this question on https://apple.stackexchange.com i think no will answer you about this over here... its code based solution site.

Comment: may be you find solution over here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46969362/develop-parental-app-in-ios

Comment: https://github.com/Allow2/Allow2iOS

Comment: also read this 
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiguidedaccessrestrictiondelegate

Comment: @AbuUlHassan , thanks but is it possible to implement this in react native.

Comment: possible to implement in ios but i am not sure for android...

Comment: okay, do you have idea for react native?

Comment: not i just installed some days ago and hav'nt tried it yet.

Comment: okay... if you find solution for react native than please let me known. i'm searching for this from last 1 week.