# Create Parental Control app iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I know this question is not related to programming, but after brief google search, i've seen that there are multiple apps in market which can block apps, read time of use spent in app and can also read text,what's app messages without jail break
I just want to know starting point to make such an app for personal use, I have no intentions to upload it to app store, so i could use API's app store don't allow

Any small link, book or reference will be appreciated

thanks

examples of apps
http://www.mindmake.com/

https://screentimelabs.com/

Comment: This is actually interesting question since I do not know too how they can read information from other apps etc.. It looks like they are selecting who is allowed to do that.

Comment: All of these solutions that I have seen install an MDM device management profile and then allow the parent to set restrictions via a web-based MDM console. From the mindmake faq, they use an MDM.  Screen time labs don't have any information on their site but I imagine they are doing the same thing.

Comment: @Paulw11 yes screen time also install profile before they set up things, so i assume MDM is my starting point!

Comment: Have found answer to a similar question.Check out this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32220377/is-it-possible-to-write-a-parental-control-app-for-ios?rq=1)

Comment: @ArslanAsim did able to do it.? If yes can you please share how.

Answer (score 0):

From what I know there is only one way in which you can achieve this on a non-jail broken iOS device.

As some other members suggested in the comments all the other apps which provide this functionality use MDM, but actually MDM is not required to achieve this.
What you need is a supervised device (which can be done from Apple Configurator 2).

So, basically you will have to create a [content filter provider](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/networkextension/content_filter_providers) which will be a basic iOS app with 2 extensions: a [filter data provider and](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/networkextension/nefilterdataprovider) a [filter control provider](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/networkextension/nefiltercontrolprovider).
Once you create the app with the 2 extensions (check the documentation, you will have to enable Network Extensions capabilities) you just need to create the configuration for it using [NEFilterProviderConfiguration](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/networkextension/nefilterproviderconfiguration) for debug mode or create and install a configuration profile using Apple Configurator 2 for production.

Apple also has an example project [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/networkextension/filtering_network_traffic) (it is old and outdated but it helps with understanding how the app should be set up).